# How do I find a formulae for $S_n$ for the sequence 3/16, 3/64,3/256, 3/1024?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this homework and I need to find the formulae for S_n in
 function of "n" The sum is sum (3)/4^(n+1) n=1 to infinity. I have calculated the 
first four terms of the series.

These are the first four:  3/16, 3/64,3/256, 3/1024. According my book I have to do:

$S_1=u_1$ and $S_2=S_1+u_2$

$S_3=S_2+u_3$  $S_4=S_3+u_4$

As $u_k={3\over4^{k+1}}$

Rewriting I got:

$u_k={3\over4^k4}$ or $3*4^{-k-1}$.

Am I right?? What I can do more from here?

Comment: Have you written out any of the $S_i$?

Answer (score 1):

One may observe that, by expanding and noticing the cancellations,
$$
(1-x)(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)=1-x^{n+1}, 
$$
giving $$
1+x+x^2+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad x \neq 1, \tag1
$$ and then put $x=\dfrac14$ in $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

In a summation, any constant can be pulled out (your constant is 3). If you do this, you will see that this is a geometric series. This means that each term only differs by a constant from the preceding term. In this case it is easy to see that this constant will be 1/4. Note that $$\frac{1}{4^n} = \frac{1^n}{4^n} = (\frac{1}{4})^n$$

Perhaps rewriting your summation in this way will help you see what is happening in this series a little more easily.

Also, a little hint: If you were to denote your summation as $3S$, where $S$ is only the series consisting of your $(\frac{1}{4})^n$ term, then consider what $$3(S-\frac{1}{4}S)$$ might simplify to.

Comment: The answer is 4^(n)-1/4^(n+1)